# How to Embed a PDF in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am trying to embed a pdf file in HTML and I am getting an error. Here is my code:

```html
<embed src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ur7D9yOxCdKND-aPoY_DkVqa9_071Eaj" width="600" height="500" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">
```

The error I am getting is : `Refused to display 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ur7D9yOxCdKND-aPoY_DkVqa9_071Eaj/edit' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

**Update:**

I have tried to use iframe and I am getting the same error

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ur7D9yOxCdKND-aPoY_DkVqa9_071Eaj"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the Embed option in Google Drive to get an iframe-able URL:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ur7D9yOxCdKND-aPoY_DkVqa9_071Eaj/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the  X-Frame-Options to something other than `sameorigin`.

I am posting this answer for those that are not sourcing from GDrive and are instead sourcing from their own site.

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade how do you do that